# Fragment in Android programming

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I think that it's a bit difficult to explain the problem but I'll try. I have a class which extends Fragment and I call it with the follow code

```
frag = new SearchDoctor();
            fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, frag);
            fragTransaction.commit();
```

Here is a part of class code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_doctor, container, false);

    spinnerCity = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cityList);
```

The first time that class is called it's alright.
But the next time when I call it thead exit at the line "rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_doctor, container, false);".

I have understand that the problem is with the fragment that contained in search_doctor.xml (layout) because I had tried it with other layouts many times and it was any problem.

Here is the layout search_doctor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cityList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/city_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/city_prompt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/specialtyList"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Αναζήτηση" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/specialtyList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cityList"
        android:entries="@array/specialty_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/specialty_prompt" />

     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/resultList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/resultList"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Χάρτης" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please if someone could help me I'll be very pleasure.
Thank's a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you calling onCreateView()?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I'm calling it and it's running. The problem as I wrote is with the fragment in the xml file.

Comment: Are you saying you're calling oncreateview manually?

Comment: @Breadbin Not manually. I call it with the code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution! I find on the forum so thank you all.

```
    public void onDestroyView() 
 {
    super.onDestroyView(); 
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to replace

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_doctor, container, false);
```

with

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_doctor, null, false);
```

Not sure if it helps but if the problem with view hierarchy that might be useful.

Comment: when add null instead of container it will crash at fragment replace or add  to framelayout.

Comment: @Andrii Gorishnii I tried it but the problem continues.